# Calculating with JavaScript within form, outputting to dynamic field, code not working

Tags: javascript, forms

Aim: This chunk of js, is designed to grab values entered into fields in a form, assign them to variables and then perform a calculation which outputs into a field on that page.

There is a short function that means out put is set as Unknown if any of the variables are undefined or empty.

My code:

```
function calculate() {
    var $u5pop = $('input[name=sv_21d]').val();
    var $sam = $('input[name=sv_25d]').val();
    var $incidence = $('input[name=sv_313]').val();
    var $treated = $('input[name=sv_312]').val();


    if ($u5pop == undefined ||$u5pop == '') {
        $u5pop = 0;
    }
    else {
        $u5pop = parseFloat($u5pop);
    }

    if ($sam == undefined ||$sam == '') {
        $sam = 0;
    }
    else {
        $sam = parseFloat($sam);
    }

    if ($incidence == undefined || $incidence == '') {
        $incidence = 0;
    }
    else {
        $incidence = parseFloat($incidence);
    }
    //
    if ($treated == undefined || $treated == '') {
        $treated = 0;
    }
    else {
        $treated = parseFloat($treated);
    }

    var $determined = $u5pop / $incidence * $treated * $sam;

    if ($determined == undefined || $determined == '') {
        $determinedOut = 'Unknown';
    }
    else {
        $determinedOut = parseFloat($determined);
    }

    $('#calculation').attr('value', $determinedOut.toFixed(2));
}
```

The output field div #calculation is:

```
<input size="18" class="calculation" id="calculation" value="Click to calculate" onfocus="calculate()"/>
```

Such that when  user click within the field it performs the calculation.

This is a structure / syntax issue I think, but everything looks good to me. Would anyone with more experienced eyes be able to see where I'm going wrong here?
At current: nothing happens (the default value remains).

Many thanks!

EDIT: This works perfectly so long as all the fields are filled in, however it FAILSS to output 'unknown' if the fields are left empty and the function is called by onfocus

Comment: Most of that Javascript code can't possibly be relevant to the problem. Try reducing the code sample to the minimum necessary.

Comment: Also: have you looked at the Javascript debugging console for any errors?

Comment: is $u5pop / $incidence * $treated * $sam; meant to be $u5pop / ($incidence * $treated * $sam); or ($u5pop / $incidence) * $treated * $sam;

Comment: HI @millimoose and david-strachan: thanks for input. Sorry to include uneccssary code, I wasn't at all sure which part was failing me, so included it all - but I can see it's bloated. 

Embarressing confession: didn't know about the Javascript debugging console - I used JSLint as a debugger, but all it seemed to complain about was errant spaces or === vs == type errors. 

David, that syntax improvement could be it, I'll give it a go, thank you.

Comment: multiplication or division by 1 results in no change, Multiplication by 0 results in 0.Division by zero results in infinity. Addition or subtraction by 1 results in change. Remember to accept or upvote answer if OK

Comment: @davidstrachan thanks, yes, I think krg is onto something below, with calling toFixed(2)  when value isn't numerical. I always try to upvote and accept :) Least I can do for everyone's kind help!

Comment: Still dividing & multiplying by zero!

Comment: @Gideon "I wasn't at all sure which part was failing me" - figuring out which part is failing you is something you should do *before* posting to SO

Comment: @davidstrachan, it's ok - because if they input zero, or leave blank any fields, the return is "Unknown", so calculation only returned if values are meaningful

Comment: @millimoose, apologies, I'll try and post more precise problems in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgpku/1/). The code failed to change the input value initially until I moved the JS function above the HTML. Perhaps that's your issue!?

Comment: Hmm, the js function is in <head>, and works ok, what's interesting here is that it works if values are in the fields, but if one of the fields is empty, focusing on the field doesn't do anything... so there must be an issue with the last part of my script

Comment: Ah, gotcha... The issue is, calling toFixed(2) if $determinedOut is not a number. Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgpku/1/) example. This example also change $var == undefined to typeof $var === 'undefined'

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense, thanks very much for your help, I'll  just see if I can make that work, and accept this if it's the solution.

Comment: Oh fantastic - This was exactly it: I learned lots from this! Nice way to solve, I didn't realise you could set variables equal to a modified version of themselves:
`$determinedOut = $determinedOut.toFixed(2);`

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at jsFiddle in other answer.
If `$u5pop` OR `$sam` OR `$treated` are changed to 0 no result obtained

If `$incidence` is changed to 0 the answer is infinity.(division by zero)

The default should be  = 1 NOT = 0

```
if ($u5pop == undefined ||$u5pop == '') {
    $u5pop = 1;
}
else {
    $u5pop = parseFloat($u5pop);
}

if ($sam == undefined ||$sam == '') {
    $sam = 1;
}
else {
    $sam = parseFloat($sam);
}

if ($incidence == undefined || $incidence == '') {
    $incidence = 1;
}
else {
    $incidence = parseFloat($incidence);
}
//
if ($treated == undefined || $treated == '') {
    $treated = 1;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right, the issue with this fix is that it returns a value for the calculation IF the user hasn't entered values, I was hoping (with my last function) to output "Unkown" in these cases. Thanks very much for your consideration